# JQuery onclick get element id, use value as variable to target classes for changing css background color

Tags: jquery

I have a list of items, each with a distinct `id` (JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r45gjykw/2/). The user can click on an item in the list and with `onclick` the JQuery gets the `id` value of the element and makes it a variable string. This string value is used to change the css `background-color` of any element that carries that value in a `class`:

So, clicking on:

```
<li id="Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities()">Guilhem Vidal</li>
```

Fires this jQuery action:

```
function highlightEntities() {
    var entclass = $(this).attr('id');
    $("."+entclass).css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```

Which should take any instance of (for example):

```
<a href="http://somefoosite/Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU" class="change_link_colour Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU">W<span class="supplied">illelmum</span> Vitalis</a>
```

...and change the background colour to "yellow".

If this is easier done in JavaScript I would accept that too.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think he means native js, he was talking about jquery.

Comment: The inline binding usage will not reference the correct `this`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Also, is this logic meant to only change the element that was clicked?  If so, there isn't a reason to find it.  The element could be passed in on the click handler.

Comment: @Taplar, no: it is fired from html `onclick="highlightEntities()"` of an `li` element, and it is meant to change the background color of other elements. I think the JSfiddle outlines the problem well with the above.

Comment: Don't force users to go to a fiddle to see your issue.  You can create a working on site example by hitting Ctrl+M or clicking the `<>` button in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using an inline binding, you should pass in the `this` on the function call, so you have access to which element was clicked.  However, I would highly suggest you look into binding dynamically.

```js
function highlightEntities(element) {
  $("."+ element.id).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilhem Vidal</li>
</ul>

<a href="http://somefoosite/Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU" class="change_link_colour Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU">W<span class="supplied">illelmum</span> Vitalis</a>
```

Comment: When I take your changes and apply them to the full scenario in the Fiddle, they do not work: https://jsfiddle.net/r45gjykw/5/ Is there a code conflict I'm not seeing?(I am trying to get it all into a code snippet in the original post, per your recommendation)

Comment: @jbrehr the load order.  You have the javascript set for "on load".  The function needs to exist before the markup, since you are doing an inline binding.  If you change it to load in the head, it works.

Comment: Works perfect now, thanks. Also, thanks for introducing me to code snippets here.

Comment: Np.  It helps everyone to have just one place to go to, :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that `this` is not working inside the block you are working with, you should use the element that is passed inside the function automatically, just change the function code to what I have below. 
Try this?

```
function highlightEntities(el) {
        let entclass = $(el.target).attr(`id`);
        $(`.${entclass}`).css(`background-color`, `yellow`);
}
```

here is a working example in a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/978927/

Comment: `this.id` would be the same as `$(this).attr('id')`, with two less function calls.  However, I believe there is an issue with `this` not being the element in this case, what with it being an inline binding.

Comment: Why are you linking to a fiddle in an answer?  Put the solution in your answer...

Comment: Although it does not matter for the JS engine, I think you should stick to one type of quotes.

Comment: Don't force people to go to an off site share site.  Make your answer be *the* answer.  Ctrl+M or click `<>` and put your solution on site.  As it currently stands, this is half an answer.  The way you bind in your fiddle, which is not displayed here in the answer, is a **very important** part to making this work.