# JQuery testing for dynamically created inline style

Tags: jquery

I have an [element which calls a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597027/jquery-onclick-get-element-id-use-value-as-variable-to-target-classes-for-chang) to create inline `style` attribute. This:

```
 <li id="Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" 
          onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilhem Vidal</li>
```

...calls this:

```
function highlightEntities(element) {
    $(element).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
    $("."+ element.id).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
    }
```

It sets the background colour for itself (and a number of other elements) and works perfectly.

```
<li id="Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" 
          onclick="highlightEntities(this)" style="background-color: yellow;">Guilhem Vidal</li>
```

Now, when the user clicks it again, I want to test if it has a style already set. This should be simple: if an inline `style` has been set, delete the style, if there is no `style`, then create one.

But my attempt at a test does not seem to do anything:

```
 function highlightEntities(element) {
    var attr = ($(element).attr("style")
    if(typeof attr !== undefined && attr !== false) {
      $(element).removeAttr("style");
      $("."+ element.id).removeAttr("style");}
    else {
      $(element).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
      $("."+ element.id).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");}
    }
```

Looking at the [variety of problems testing for an attribute brings](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-check-if-an-element-has-attribute-using-jquery-and-javascript), I may not be testing correctly?

May thanks in advance.

Comment: Easiest approach would be to use a css class instead, and `toggleClass()`  https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass

Comment: @Taplar So...in the function `highlightEntities(element)` I use `toggleClass()` to get the wanted class (which is already styled with CSS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof` returns a `String`, so your test should be:

```
if (typeof attr !== "undefined" && attr !== false)
```

Otherwise, the first clause always evaluates to true!

Here's a snippet showing that this fix make the original function work:

```js
function highlightEntities(element) {
  var attr = $(element).attr("style");
  if(typeof attr !== "undefined" && attr !== false) {
    $(element).removeAttr("style");
    $("."+ element.id).removeAttr("style");}
  else {
    $(element).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
    $("."+ element.id).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li id="Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" 
          onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilhem Vidal</li>
</ul>

<div class="Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU">Other element with class matching trigger id</div>
```

However, as stated by @Taplar, the recommended way to do this is using jQuery's `toggleClass()` or [ES6 `classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Note that jQuery `toggleClass` is more widely compatible with older browsers. You can check `classList` support [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=classlist).

Here's a solution **with and without jQuery**:

```js
// Vanilla Javascript
function highlightEntities(element) {

  element.classList.toggle("highlighted");
  document.querySelectorAll("." + element.id).forEach( e => e.classList.toggle("highlighted") );

}

// jQuery
function jqHighlightEntities(element) {

  $(element).toggleClass("highlighted");
  $("." + element.id).toggleClass("highlighted");

}
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li id="Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" 
          onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilhem Vidal</li>
</ul>

<div class="Guilhem_Vidal_MSP-AU">Other element with class matching trigger id</div>
```

Comment: I see that problem, thanks! However, even with the modification...it doesn't have an effect :/

Comment: I've edited with snippets to show that it's working :)